# CollectionView flickers unsorted array when sorting

Tags: swift, sorting, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uicollectionview

Here is the problem.

After creating an array of json objects, I sort them. When I load the controller, the collection view flickers the unsorted array and then presents the sorted array (Please refer to the demo below).

[CollectionView Flicker Problem Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgDWb.gif)

I've tried a few ways of going about this problem.

1. GCD to first complete the sorting and then reload the collection view.
2. GCD to remove the array and then continue with the request.
3. Dispatch Async the sorting and collection view reload.

Here is my code

```
  ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        self.collectionView?.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()

        guard let dictionaries = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

        dictionaries.forEach({ (key, value) in
            guard let dictionary = value as? [String: Any] else { return }

            var post = Post(user: user, dictionary: dictionary)
            post.id = key

            self.posts.sort(by: { (p1, p2) -> Bool in
                return p1.creationDate.compare(p2.creationDate) == .orderedDescending
            })
            self.posts.append(post)
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()

        }, withCancel: { (err) in
            print("Failed to fetch like info for post:", err)
        })
    })
```

I really don't know what else to do.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You're telling the collection view to update its contents (by calling `reloadData()`) after every update. This causes the flicker. To prevent this, only tell the collection view to update itself after you're done with all the updates:

```
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    self.collectionView?.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()

    guard let dictionaries = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

    dictionaries.forEach({ (key, value) in
        guard let dictionary = value as? [String: Any] else { return }

        var post = Post(user: user, dictionary: dictionary)
        post.id = key

        self.posts.sort(by: { (p1, p2) -> Bool in
            return p1.creationDate.compare(p2.creationDate) == .orderedDescending
        })
        self.posts.append(post)

    }, withCancel: { (err) in
        print("Failed to fetch like info for post:", err)
    })
    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
})
```

Comment: This fixed the problem! I also have a method that has a fetch request within a fetch request.. The same problem persists.. Any idea how I could fix that?